# logback HTMLLayout page too wide

Tags: java, html, html-table, logback

I'm using this layout with the `RollingFileAppender`.

Everything works really well, but there's just one problem: typically the pixel width of the table produced is simply too wide.

This is particularly so because many of my test method names are typically very long... they go off the right edge of the window and I'm constantly having to scroll right and left.

I'm also using (Firefox) the NoSquint add-in, where you can zoom the text size pretty much independently of the "general zoom".  But this doesn't really work.  I just want to stipulate maximum (and minimum, why not?) pixel widths for each table column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone interested, the solution I found was to insert HTML *soft hyphens* (`&shy;`) in outputted `String`s containing *camel case* text and/or dots (also making text smaller).

- Modify the *logback.xml* and *logback-test.xml* files as follows:

```
    <!--  <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">  -->
    <encoder class="utils.MyLayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
            ....
```

- Copy the `LayoutWrapperEncoder` file from your extracted logback source jar and rename as `MyLayoutWrapperEncoder`.

- Modify a couple of methods in this class

```
void writeHeader() throws IOException {
    if (layout != null && (outputStream != null)) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        appendIfNotNull(sb, layout.getFileHeader());
        appendIfNotNull(sb, layout.getPresentationHeader());
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(CoreConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR);

            // replace a couple of header names with shorter and smaller text            
            String outString = sb.toString();
            outString = outString.replaceAll( "MethodOfCaller", "MoC" ).replaceAll( "RelativeTime", "RT" );
            outString = outString.replaceAll( "LineOfCaller", "LoC" );
            // make text smaller
            outString = outString.replaceAll( "<td class=(.+?)>", "<td style=\"font-size:13px\" class=$1>" );

            outputStream.write(convertToBytes( outString ));
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
public void doEncode(E event) throws IOException {
    String txt = layout.doLayout(event);

    /*
    * Identify "camel case" upper case letters and also dots in all <TD> output...
    * and insert soft hyphen at this point.  Also make text smaller.
    */
    Pattern tDPattern = Pattern.compile( "<td class=.+?>(.*?)</td>" );
    StringBuilder wholeStringSB = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher tDMatcher = tDPattern.matcher( txt );
    int lastWholeString = 0;
    while( tDMatcher.find() ){
        String tDContents = tDMatcher.group( 1 );
        Matcher camelCaseAndDotMatcher = Pattern.compile("[a-z]([A-Z\\.])").matcher( tDContents );
        StringBuilder camelCaseAndDotSB = new StringBuilder();
        int last = 0;
        while( camelCaseAndDotMatcher.find() ){
            camelCaseAndDotSB.append( tDContents.substring( last,  camelCaseAndDotMatcher.start( 1 ) ));
            camelCaseAndDotSB.append( "&shy;" + camelCaseAndDotMatcher.group(1) );
            last = camelCaseAndDotMatcher.end(1);
        }
        if( last > 0 ){
            // ... at least one camel case UC char and/or dot WAS found...
            wholeStringSB.append( txt.substring( lastWholeString,  tDMatcher.start( 1 )) );
            camelCaseAndDotSB.append( tDContents.substring(last));    
            wholeStringSB.append( camelCaseAndDotSB.toString().trim() );
            lastWholeString = tDMatcher.end();
        }
    }
    wholeStringSB.append( txt.substring( lastWholeString ).trim() );
    txt = wholeStringSB.toString();
    // make text smaller
    txt = txt.replaceAll( "<td class=(.+?)>", "<td style=\"font-size:13px\" class=$1>" );


    outputStream.write(convertToBytes(txt));
    if (immediateFlush)
        outputStream.flush();
}
```

PS I haven't found out where the CSS for the various "class" attributes of these different TD elements are located (or, if not actual files, how they are generated or whatever).  Anyone know?

PPS Although a promising approach, these soft hyphens don't appear to be applied to the final, "Message", column. More research needed for a really excellent solution!